# ActiveX component can't create object. Hasp in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, dll, hasp

I wanted to create object of HASP app in VBA in Excel, but I have such error:
*Run-time error '429': ActiveX component can't create object.*

I installed hasp_com_windows.dll in SYSWOW64 folder and hasp_com_windows_x64.dll in System32. I also add reference to *Aladdin Knowledge Systems Ltd. HASP SRM API Library*.

My OS: Windows 8.1. 64 bit

My VBA code:

```
Sub TestHasp()

Dim haspApp As AKSHASP.HaspApplication
Set haspApp = CreateObject("AKSHASP.HaspApplication")  'here is an error

End Sub
```

Here are these dll files: [hasp dll](http://www.sendspace.com/filegroup/AS4D4qx7so1uLoxHD%2Fbq7g)

=======
Edit:
When I use:

```
Dim haspApp as new AKSHASP.HaspApplicaton
```

I get: *Compile error: User-defined type not defined.*

Comment: open VBE and hit F2 to see Object Browser. Find the library and go through the classes. It makes a little or no sense to Dim an object using half early half late binding. Try to use an early binding only ie. `Dim haspApp as new AKSHASP.HaspApplicaton`

Comment: For what should I go through the classes? If I I use this early binding I get: _Compile error: User-defined type not defined_.

Comment: To get familiar with the library you're using :)

Comment: Okey, so I didn't know that I can do sth like this. Now I know. :)
And did you meet with such compile error?

Answer (score 0):

The error is consistent with the DLL not being installed properly.  Try using `Tools`/`References`/`Browse...` then select either or both of the DLLs to install them.  You may need to run Excel an an Administrator before you do this, so that Excel can write to the Registry.